# value always the same, different in database Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

This is my ArticleController

```
def new
   @article = Article.new
end

def create
  #render plain: params[:article].inspect
  @article = Article.new(super_params)
  if @article.save
    flash[:notice] = "Article has been created"
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def super_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
end

def show
  @article = Article.find_by( params[:id] )
end
```

The main problem is that whenever i do: articles/2 or 5 or 6 i get the same article which was created as first. In database records are good i have only this problem with render it.

Comment: can you show you routes?

Answer (score 0):

I know, i did:

```
find_by
```

Instead of

```
find
```

Sory for trouble...